# SQL запрос на обновление по дате

Tags: sql, mysql

Помогите решить проблему.
Есть запрос:

```
UPDATE schedule SET used = 1 WHERE `date` < NOW();
```

Нужно чтобы поле used вставало в 1, когда дата из поля меньше на 30 минут чем нынешнея
в общем через 30 минут после даты указанной в записи поле used обновлялось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE schedule SET used = 1 WHERE `date` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```

Comment: запрос логически верен, я и так пробовал. но почему то через 30 минут used все равно на позиции 0

Забыл добавить, поле date имеет тип datetime 2015-02-24 23:06:00

Comment: Спасибо, все решил, на сервере таймзона стояла не верная.